# Vector /List work with Storage in lwuit?

Tags: storage, lwuit

I try to save vector or default list on storage. All work fine until i close the application and open again. When i call to Storage , the storage don't find this vector.

Do have Problem to use this objects with Storage in lwuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writeObject method accepts a second parameter as a Object. It returns true or false. If you object is suitable in the Storage you will get true. Try to put this vector and see what returns this method.

Last week I try to put a custom object and it doesn't work. I think hashtables can be in Storage, but ListModels doesn't.

[Storage API](http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/iodocs/com/sun/lwuit/io/Storage.html#writeObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)